Image can not be used as JSX component ReactNative JS
Hello i am new to ReactNative and JS. Just following some tutorials and i have run into a problem.
So i have a folder with some elements like
const products = [ { id: 1, name: 'Ultimate Pepperoni', image: 'https://notjustdev-dummy.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/food/peperoni.png', price: 12.99, },
and in main file it is imported like
import products from '../../assets/data/products';
then const is created like
const product = products[0]; 
where i can use id,name and price but when i try to use Image tag to display image like this
 <Image source={{uri: product.image}} style={styles.image}/>
there is an error saying that Image can not be used as JSX component and JSX element class does not support attributes because it does not have a 'props' property.ts(2607).
I appreciate any kind of help.
these are all imports that i am using
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'; import Colors from '../../constants/Colors'; import products from '../../assets/data/products';
I have tried to use   <Image source={{uri: product.image}} style={styles.image}/>
but i got an error saying that Image can not be used as JSX componene and JSX element class does not support attributes because it does not have a 'props' property.ts(2607).

add Image to your imports from react-native
